# Are there any publicly available test nets that run pallet contracts?

Tags: pallet-contracts, test-network

We are looking to deploy a demo dapp to a live test net. Do any of these exist or are we better using a service like [onfinality](https://onfinality.io/api-service) or deploying our own test net?

Data persistence is not that important. As long as we could monitor when the network restarted and redeploy and populate our contract when this happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[There is a rococo parachain](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io#/explorer) which is maintained by Parity. Instructions for its faucet can be found [along with its source code](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo#rococo-deployment).

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the faucet in matrix and received a note saying that 100 ROC had been transferred to my account. However, these didn't show up in polkadot-js/apps. The extrinsic hash is `0xcd35029f8072110f1c612bf379dac32f7561d66cbe58b74c4aabb6f0df4aaf7c`. Do I need to issue the drip command with the parachain ID `9230`?

Comment: It is explained in the document I linked: `!drip YOUR_SS_58_ADDRESS:1002`. The id is `1002` and not `9320`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

We described available networks in the [documentation](https://docs.openbrush.io/deployment). It contains instructions on how to use each network. If something is not precise, outdated, or a new network is born, you can create an issue in [repository](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts). We will fix it=)