# On which public testnet can I deploy an ink! smart contract for testing

Tags: ink, rococo

In the deprecated Canvas repo the Rococo Canvas testnet is mentioned, however, I can't find any working rpc url. I can't connect to the [RPC linked](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-canvas-rpc.polkadot.io#/explorer) there, so I'd assume it's deprecated as well.

On polkadot.js/apps I found a link to the Rococo Contracts which seems to do the job as well, however, I don't find any information on how I can get tokens to deploy my ink! smart contract. Does anybody know a faucet?

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

- I was able to solve it by sending the following command to the [faucet channel on element](https://matrix.to/#/#rococo-faucet:matrix.org): `!drip YOUR_SS_58_ADDRESS:1002`

Comment: If https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/are-there-any-publicly-available-test-nets-that-run-pallet-contracts is not sufficient please comment there 